# How to reproduce "collect feedback workflow 2010" using Sharepoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual-studio

We are using SharePoint 2013 Server, it is a greenfield project. So in this case, the intention is to use new Workflow Manager to develop workflow, which is said better performance and robust. (All software are on premise)

However, there are many workflows we are using is actually similar or close to Collect Feedback workflow, which is an OOTB SP 2010 workflow. So if we use SP 2010 workflow engine for these, it will save some efforts.

So here comes to the decision point, should we keep develop workflow based on these SP2010 workflows? Or is there any tutorial online to reproduce them as a SP 2013 workflow. I had  googled around but could not find an article for this yet.

If we do go down the track of using SP2013 workflow engine, should we use SP Designer or Visual Studio declaritive workflow, or doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was decided new workflows 2013 for any entirely new workflow. For those workflow based on the OOTB workflows, it will be remain in 2010 mode. Because to reproduce them isn't an easy job.

And we are using VS to do the workflow because of source control purpose.